# Why is this CSS not disabling the text-decoration in the hyperlink?

Tags: html, css

I was using the CSS from this [codepen](http://codepen.io/brenden/pen/RNZXqx) to create a cool hyperlink underline effect on hover.  But when I go to implement it, I can still see the text-decoration being applied to the hyperlink even though I have it set to *none* for the *a* tag.  What is the issue?

EDIT: I want the cool hyperlink effect to be applied to the *View Battle Worlds Only* link.

**CSS**

```
section.custom_view h2, section.custom_view h3, section.custom_view h4 {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 150%;
  padding-top: 1.25em;
  margin-right: 0.625em; }

section.custom_view ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden; }

section.custom_view li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0.625em; }

section.custom_view li a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 150%;
  padding-top: 1.25em;
  text-decoration: none; }

section.custom_view li a, section.custom_view li a:visited, section.custom_view li a:hover, section.custom_view li a:active {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s color ease;
  text-decoration: none; }

section.custom_view li a:hover {
  color: #990000; }

section.custom_view li a.before:before, section.custom_view li a.after:after {
  content: "";
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute; }

section.custom_view li a.after:after {
  bottom: -0.25em; }

section.custom_view li a.before:before, section.custom_view li a.after:after {
  height: 5px;
  height: 0.35rem;
  width: 0;
  background: #990000; }

section.custom_view li a.third:after, section.custom_view li a.sixth:before, section.custom_view li a.sixth:after {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%); }

section.custom_view li a.before:hover:before, section.custom_view li a.after:hover:after {
  width: 100%; }
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <! -- some more HTML -->
<section class='content'>
    <ul class='breadcrumbs'>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li>Searching for Worlds</li>
    </ul>
    <section class='custom_view'>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h2>Viewing All Trials</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="third after" href="/search?limit=15&amp;locale=en&amp;offset=0&amp;recruiting_status=Recruiting&amp;search_header_menu_left=Viewing+All+Battle+Worlds&amp;search_header_menu_right=View+All+Worlds&amp;search_terms=Mars&amp;zip_code=90033">View Battle Worlds Only</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
   <! -- some more HTML -->
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks the fiddle works, oddly enough there's still a text decoration that appears on a hover as the animation is starting in my actual application...Not sure what it could be though - any ideas?

Comment: The code inspector says "text-decoration: none" is winning in the computed properties in Firefox/Chrome and I don't want to do the asterisk because I don't want to apply the styles to all a elements.

Comment: Actually, I see *a {    color: blue; }* that includes a *text-decoration: none* that is crossed out.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is being applied to the `section` element with the class `custom_view` because it is being declared that way in all your CSS selectors:

```
section.custom_view
```

However, your `section` in the HTML has a class of `content`:

```
<section class='content'>
```

To make this work, you need to match the class.

Either change the class in the CSS to `content` for all instances of `custom_view`

**or**

change the class for the `section` in the HTML to `class='custom_view'`

Comment: Ah I see, you had a class of `trial_view` on the inner `section` when I had looked at this. Must be some CSS elsewhere that is overriding the `text-decoration:none` if this is still an issue. Developer tools should show you where that CSS is coming from.

Comment: Wherever it may be coming from, your CSS selector here needs to be more specific, per the [specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). If you could identify the CSS selector that is winning out, we can help you figure out a way to beat it.